# What is a good word/adjective for a protein jiggling and wiggling? VIBRANT?

Tags: vocabulary

I am writing up an essay about a protein macro-molecule inside the cell. This protein is extremely dynamic and constantly jiggles and wiggles. What is a good word/adjective to describe this feature?

Originally, I chose the word "vibrant", but an expert told me there might be a better word. Is "vibrant" OK in this context? Any idea for an alternative word?

Comment: Of the words you've already used, "dynamic" sounds like a better fit than "vibrant." Despite the etymology, "vibrant" doesn't really suggest motion to me; for me it's mostly a synonym of "rich" in the sense of "rich colors" or "rich experiences." (For example: The Google Ngram viewer suggests that the most common nouns used following "vibrant" are "colors," "life," "voice," "personality" and "tones.")

Comment: For something with a biological connotation I would say "Motile". Sumelic is right about vibrant,  try "vibratory" instead if "motile" doesn't suit.

Comment: You probably want to shy away from any hint of volitional movement (lively, sprightly, vigorous, vital, animated); 'motile' as defined by ODO carries the caveat (bolded) (**of cells, gametes, and single-celled organisms**) capable of motion, and _highly motile_ is used.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I've seen it additionally as "exhibiting or capable of movement" by MW.

Comment: Off the top of the bean (but not one word): perpetual motion. "This protein macro-molecule is in a state of perpetual motion."

Comment: A really far-out word: Choreic. Chorea (aka St. Vitus's Dance, aka Sydenham chorea) is a  disorder of the central nervous system characterized by uncontrollable irregular brief jerky movements. Hence, "It's as if the macro-molecule is doing  St. Vitus'  dance." (Some folks might find this offensive.) The dance of St. Vitus, by the way,  was performed on the feast day of St. Vitus, a 4th century Christian martyr (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitus).

Comment: @rhetorician definitely a nifty word. I think it comes from the Greek for chorus which would suggest volition, though only if it was highly scrutinized.

Comment: Thank you all! I like 'jerking'...., but still searching....

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of the bean (but not one word): *perpetual motion*.

> "This protein macro-molecule is in a state of perpetual motion."

A really far-out word: choreic. Chorea (aka St. Vitus's Dance, aka Sydenham chorea) is a disorder of the central nervous system characterized by uncontrollable irregular brief jerky movements. Hence,

> "It's as if the macro-molecule is doing St. Vitus' dance." (Some folks might find this offensive, however.)

In the Middle Ages in Germany and Latvia the dance of [St. Vitus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitus) was performed on the eponymous feast day in front of the statue of St. Vitus, a 4th century Christian martyr.

Herky-jerky is another possibility, which [Farlex](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/herky-jerky) defines as "progressing in a fitful or jerky manner."

> "The molecule moves in continuous herky-jerky fashion."

Other possibilities:

> - convulsions, or continuous convulsions
> - writhing and twitching
> - squirming and twisting
> - (the cell is characterized by) moto perpetuo (see my first suggestion, above)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps ***[energetic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/energetic)***, "showing or involving great activity or vitality"

I don't think there's any volition implied in the term, it can refer to a reaction or a system.

Answer (score 0):

**Dynamic** is a good option as mentioned in the comments.

Other options are **fluid** or even **restless** if you want to personify the protein.

I agree with avoiding vibrant.

Answer (score 0):

Another word to describe this "jiggling and wiggling" is **agitated**.

Answer (score -1):

You could give new life to the word **ebullient**.

Comment: When I think of cheerful proteins I normally picture a 3" T-bone steak. Might just be me though.

Comment: You and Fred Flintstone.

Comment: Mmmm.... Brontosaurus.....

Comment: "Cheerful" was the word's figurative meaning, BTW. An earlier meaning, now no longer in use, was "agitated, bubbling".

Comment: I like "motile" or "vibratory" to describe a protein that's in (frequent) motion. Without knowing the specific nature of motion, vibratory might not be apt.